# How to draw bar graph in matplotlib after group by about two columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Dataframe like this -

| CITY | BANK | DEPOSIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NewYork | ABC | 10 |
| Seattle | ABC | 30 |
| NewYork | LMN | 99 |
| NewYork | PQR | 100 |
| Seattle | PQR | 50 |
| Seattle | LMN | 43 |

There are multiple cities in the column. A bank can be present in many cities and a city can have many banks(many to many relation). In a city, every bank has certain deposit('DEPOSIT') column.

I want to draw a bar graph to plot the top 5 cities according to their total deposits(across all the banks in that city), and for each city, I want to have 3 banks with top deposit in that city, so basically 15 plots on x axis.

The X axis should have city names(total of 5), and each city should have 3 bars with banks having maximum deposits(figure on the top).

**What I have tried:**

I tried a couple of things, first tried to group by city and then banks, then reset the index to have a dataframe to plot. But then couldnt figure out how to go ahead with plotting part.

Here's the code(which doesnt work, but I tried).

```
grp_city = df.groupby(['CITY','BANK'])['DEPOSIT'].sum().reset_index()
grp_city.sort_values(by = grp_city.groupby('CITY')['DEPOSIT'].sum().reset_index()['DEPOSIT'])
```

I tried several other things but they doesn't seem to work either. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the top 3 bank deposits, we can group the data twice, first by city and bank and then by city only. Separately (to find the top 5 cities by total deposit), group by city and return the 5 largest deposit sum. Then I just filtered the data to make plotting simple.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example data
np.random.seed(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'CITY': np.random.choice(['NewYork', 'Seattle', 'Boston', 'LosAngeles', 'Chicago', 'Washington', 'Denver'], size=50, p=[1/7 for i in range(7)]),
                   'BANK': np.random.choice(['ABC', 'LMN', 'PQR', 'BDR', 'BBB', 'NUB', 'INT'], size=50, p=[1/7 for i in range(7)]),
                   'DEPOSIT': np.random.randint(1, 300, size=50)})

# Group data by city and by the top 3 bank deposits
grp_city = df.groupby(['CITY', 'BANK'])['DEPOSIT'].max()
grp_city = grp_city.groupby(level='CITY').nlargest(3).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df_max_deposits = grp_city.reset_index()

# Top 5 cities by total deposit
top_cities = df.groupby(['CITY'])['DEPOSIT'].sum().nlargest(5).index

# Filter the cities that we want in the plot
plot_df = df_max_deposits.query('CITY in @top_cities')

# Finally plot the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8))
sns.set_theme(context='talk')

sns.barplot(x='CITY', y='DEPOSIT', hue='BANK', data=plot_df)

plt.legend(loc=(0.1, 0.6))
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: I don't know why the bars are not aligned with the city names, but if I had to guess, I would say it's because of the n of different banks.

Comment: Thanks, i am giving this a try. Will let you know how it come out for me.

Comment: Hi, the plots looks fine but I am not sure why the cities are not in order of maximum deposits? Can you help here?

Comment: That's because `grp_city` isn't sorted like that. Add `.sort_values(ascending=False)` between `nlargest(3)` and `reset_index()`.

Comment: I am really sorry for bothering but it still doesnt work as expected for me. It is now better but it is not quite sorting about the cities. It seems to me like it is sorting about the Banks, like the highest grossing city with above modification is placed at third number, and second highest grossing is placed at first position. But since the second highest grossing city has a bank with a bank with highest deposit(which gives it a big bar), it places it on first position. Collectively the city that is at third has maximum depositing banks. So, it should come first. Can you please help again?

Comment: P.S: I have made the changes like this based on your comment `grp_city = grp_city.groupby(level='CITY').nlargest(3).sort_values(ascending = False).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Comment: @PankajMishra No problem. Sorry for taking so long. I think I misunderstood what you wanted. You're right, it is sorting based on deposits (city with the highest deposit come first and so on). What you actually want is the same order of `top_cities`, right? That is, sort by the total of deposits. If so, you can specify `order=top_cities` to `sns.barplot()`.

Comment: Thanks @danpl. With your suggestion and some modifications from my end, I think I have been able to solve this problem. I will post solution once I validate it some more. I will be more than grateful if you could have a look at it once I publish.

Comment: @PankajMishra You're welcome. Sure, I'll take a look. If my answer was useful to you, please consider voting and/or accepting as an answer.

Comment: It was very close to what I wanted. Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
******************MATPLOTLIB*********************


/import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


/fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

/fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(5,5))

********************************************************************

#lineplot
/ax.plot(df['name'],df['age'],color='green', linestyle='-', linewidth=3,marker='o',markersize=10)
/ax.plot(df['name'],df['weight'],color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=3,marker='o',markersize=10)

#scatterplot
/ax.scatter(df['name'],df['age'], marker='o',c=['green'], edgecolor='black')

#barplot
/ax.bar(x2_index,df['weight'],color='red',width=0.15,edgecolor='black',label='Weight')
/ax.bar(x2_index,df['age'],color='red',width=0.15,edgecolor='black',label='Weight')

#pieplot
/plt.pie(df['age'],colors=['red','green','blue'],labels=['abu','leo','moni'],autopct='%1.1f%%')

#hist
/plt.hist(name,bins=3)

#boxplot
/plt.boxplot([df['age'],df['weight']])

************************************************************************

/plt.title("demo",fontsize=15)
/plt.xlabel("xaxis",fontsize=12)
/plt.ylabel("yaxis",fontsize=12)
/plt.xlim(0,60)
/plt.ylim(0,60)
/plt.grid()
/plt.legend()
/ax.legend(loc='upper right')
/plt.savefig('plot1.png',bbox_inches='tight')
/plt.show()

**************************MATRIX HISTOGRAM SUBPLOT***********************************************

/fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(5,5))
/ax[0][0].hist(name,bins=3)
/ax[0][1].scatter(df['name'],df['age'])
/ax[1][0].hist(name,bins=3)
/ax[1][1].hist(name,bins=3)
/ax[0][0].set_title("demo1")
/ax[0][1].set_title("demo2")

*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************

*************************SEABORN***************************************

/import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
/import seaborn as sns


/fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

/fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,figsize=(5,5))

***********************************HUE***************************************
/df1=df.loc[df['ABC'].isin(['aa','bb','cc'])]

**************************************************************************

/sns.lineplot(x='name',y='age',data=df1,hue='cat',ax=ax,markers='o')
/sns.histplot(x='cat',data=df,ax=ax)
/sns.scatterplot(x='name',y='age',data=df1,hue='cat',ax=ax)
/sns.jointplot(x='weight',y='age',data=df,kind='hex',ax=ax)
/sns.pairplot(df,kind='scatter',ax=ax)
/sns.barplot(x='name',y='age',data=df1,hue='yesno',ax=ax)
/sns.countplot(x='yesno',data=df,ax=ax)
/sns.barplot(x='name',y='age',data=df1,hue='yesno',ax=ax[0])
/sns.countplot(x='yesno',data=df,ax=ax[1])
/sns.regplot(x='weight',y='age',data=df,ax=ax)
/sns.lmplot(x='weight',y='age',data=df)


*****************************************************************************

/plt.title("demo",fontsize=15)
/plt.xlabel("xaxis",fontsize=12)
/plt.ylabel("yaxis",fontsize=12)
/plt.ylim(0,60)
/plt.xlim(0,30)
/plt.grid()
/plt.legend()
/plt.legend(loc='upper right')
/plt.savefig('plot1.png',bbox_inches='tight')
/plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. Also, why are all these lines prefixed with `/`? That's not valid Python.